Using a Maui Control in Avalonia
I am trying to use a ZXing Maui control to read a barcode using a mobile's camera. It is activating the camera correctly but it is not reading the QR Code. My code is as follows:
using Avalonia.Controls;
    using Avalonia.Maui.Controls;
    using ZXing.Net.Maui;
    using ZXing.Net.Maui.Controls;

    namespace QRPayment
    {
    public partial class QRPaymentView : UserControl
    {
        private string barcode;

        public QRPaymentView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        CameraBarcodeReaderView cameraBarcodeReaderView =    (CameraBarcodeReaderView)this.Get<MauiControlHost>("CameraReader").Content!;
        cameraBarcodeReaderView.Options = new BarcodeReaderOptions
        {
            Formats = BarcodeFormats.OneDimensional,AutoRotate = true, Multiple = false
        };
        cameraBarcodeReaderView.CameraLocation = cameraBarcodeReaderView.CameraLocation ==  CameraLocation.Rear ? CameraLocation.Rear : CameraLocation.Front;
    }
    
        protected void BarcodesDetected(object sender, BarcodeDetectionEventArgs e)
    {
            BarcodeResult res = e.Results[0];
            barcode = res.Value;
    }
     }
    }

The XAML file is as follows:
<UserControl
    x:Class="Screens.QRPayment.QRPaymentView"
    xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
    xmlns:controls="using:Avalonia.Maui.Controls"
    xmlns:mauiControls="using:Microsoft.Maui.Controls"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Screens.ZimQRPayment"
    xmlns:zxing="using:ZXing.Net.Maui.Controls"
    d:DesignHeight="450"
    d:DesignWidth="400"
    x:DataType="vm:QRPaymentViewModel"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <DockPanel
        Margin="2"
        LastChildFill="True"
        RenderOptions.BitmapInterpolationMode="HighQuality">
        
        <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
            <Button
                Name="Cancel"
                Height="50"
                Margin="5"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                Background="Red"
                Command="{Binding CancelCommand}"
                CornerRadius="10"
                Foreground="White">
                Cancel
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Margin="5">
                <controls:MauiControlHost x:Name="CameraReader" Width="300" Height="400">
                    <zxing:CameraBarcodeReaderView
                        BarcodesDetected="BarcodesDetected" />
                </controls:MauiControlHost>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Margin="5">
                <TextBlock
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    Text="PLease Scan QR Code" />
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </DockPanel>
</UserControl>


The event for a detected barcode (BarcodesDetected) is never called. Or the control is not detecting the barcode.
What am I missing here?

Did you eventually figure it out?
